I am getting "Trying to send message to 'null' destination agent" error while running the simulation model
I am working on the simulation modelling of "import container transportation from seaport to dryport".
I have created following agents:

Kandla_port
Dryport
Railyard
Train
Containers
order


Import containers are received by the Kandla port. There are two types of containers (1) twentyFootContainers (2) fortyFootContainers.
Here, 1 twentyFootContainer = 1 TEU & 1 fortyFootContainer = 2 TEUs.
This containers are generated at Kandla port using two separate events according to arrival rate.
Now, the condition is that if number of TEUs > (0.5*capacity), the kandla port sends the train request to the railyard. Here, capacity is the maximum carrying capacity of train in TEUs that is 90 in our case.
So kandla port will send the request to Railyard as soon as number TEUs crosses value of 45. To send the request I have created one function that checks the trainRequest condition after each container arrival.
I checked the BUILD MODEL feature. There is no error.
I am facing the issue during the simulation run. As soon as the number of TEUs reaches the value greater than 45 (i.e, 46 or 47), the simulation is sending the following error.

Error:
    Exception during discrete event execution:
     root.kandla:
     Trying to send message to 'null' destination agent
     java.lang.RuntimeException: root.kandla:
     Trying to send message to 'null' destination agent
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.AgentExtensionImpl.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ie.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.send(Unknown Source)
    at import_containers.Kandla.requestTrainIfNeeded(Kandla.java:749)
    at import_containers.Kandla.executeActionOf(Kandla.java:726)
    at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.je(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$i.run(Unknown Source)

I have used following java codes:
Event 1 - TwentyFootContainers
    int containerId = containerIdCounter++; // Assign a unique ID to each container
    Container container = new Container(true, weight, containerId); // Initialize a 20-foot container
    twentyFootContainerCount++;
    totalTeusArrived++;
    if (Math.random() < roadModePercentage) {
    teusByRoad++;
    } else {
    teusByRailPending++;
    requestTrainIfNeeded();  // Call the function to check if a train is needed
    }

Event 2 - FortyFootContainers
    int containerId = containerIdCounter++; // Assign a unique ID to each container
    Container container = new Container(false, weight, containerId); // Initialize a 40-foot container
    fortyFootContainerCount++;
    totalTeusArrived += 2;
    if (Math.random() < roadModePercentage) {
    teusByRoad += 2;
    } else {
    teusByRailPending += 2;
    requestTrainIfNeeded();  // Call the function to check if a train is needed
    }

Function - requestTrainIfNeeded
if (!trainRequested && teusByRailPending > capacity * 0.4) {
     Order order = new Order(this, teusByRailPending);
     send(order, railyard);
     trainRequested = true;
}


simple... railyard doesn't have a value sometimes...impossible to tell you why

Thanks for the response. I called the railyard agent in the function using "raiyard" parameter which has a reference to Railyard agent. What is the solution in this case?

You need to make sure that railyard is actually pointing to something. So either add a check around that or check your model setup why it sometimes is null. We cannot help with that as it depends entirely on your specific model. Start with some traceln() commands and investigate step by step

oh, and only use the "anylogic" tag, this suffices for SOF
